# matplotlib - globally set margins

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't see the reason why, but the default behaviour of matplotlib plot is to have margins before and after the x-axis

[image]

Is there a way to fix this globally for all plots in my notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured that out. Add this to the start of your page:

```
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0
```

Apparently matplotlib default margins are set to 0.05:

```
#axes.xmargin        : .05  # x margin.  See `axes.Axes.margins`
#axes.ymargin        : .05  # y margin.  See `axes.Axes.margins`
```

So changing this value would globally change it for your plots.